# In Laravel how to display the the image files from storage/app/ and display?

Tags: php, linux, laravel, storage, laravel-10

I created the laravel project and the problem is that the admin users are filling the form along jpg file and the file is being uploaded and being stored in storage directory but where the image aim to be displayed to public users it is not being displayed.

```
{{url('/storage/app/news/' . $val2->id . '.png') }}"
```

Although the file exists at that locations.

I tried with changing the file reading mode permission for server.

I have not moved to deployment phase although, the issue is in Laravel development server.

The file is not being displayed at web while file is there don't know access issue or what else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of ideas! You might want to make sure you've run `php artisan storage:link` to make a symbolic link between where your files are being uploaded and where you want to access them in the application.

You also might want to use Laravel's `storage_path()` helper function in conjunction with `asset()` rather than `url()`. This should guarantee that you're always accessing files within your storage directory. So your code would look like:

```
"{{ asset(storage_path('app/news/' . $val->id . '.png')) }}"
```

There's a few notes on this in the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#the-public-disk) if you want to check it out.

Comment: I have seen the Laravel documentation but not founded there. But I resolved this as I placed the news directory inside storage/app/public and it worked by asset function 
asset('storage/news/' . $val2->id . '.png')

But you are saying also right thing can you refer any tutorial or something where I can get clear my confusions according to your point of view?

Comment: Oh great, glad you resolved it! Not sure of a specific tutorial for this, but Laracasts cover storing/retrieving image files pretty in-depth in their [Laravel From Scratch](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch/episodes/64) series.